# How can I copy a database in Azure SQL Server to Azure SQL Manged Instance in different Azure Subscription

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I created an Azure SQL managed instance using terraform in Azure Subscription A.

I am trying to copy the databases in an existing Azure SQL Server in Subscription B to the SQL Managed Instances I created in Subscription A, please how can I go about this?

I cannot find any resource that addresses a similar issue yet.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be on topic for [so]; perhaps it would be better on [dba.se]. Please read *their [tour](//dba.stackexchange.com/tour)* first before asking; you failed to read the [tour] here before posting, even though you were prompted to when you signed up.

Comment: I may not have the necessary knowledge on how best to ask questions here, but I would be glad if you had answers to my question

Comment: As I stated, your question isn't on-topic here; it's unlikely to get answers because this isn't a site where such questions get answers.

Answer (score 0):

To copy resources between subscriptions within the same tenant please try [Azure Resource Mover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/overview). With it you can even decide an automatic cleanup of resources in the source subscription, if you want to delete them after the move.

Another option you have is to [export the databases as bacpacs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-the-sqlpackage-utility) to an Azure Storage Account (subscription 1), possibly copy the bacpacs to a second storage acccount on subscription #2 using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows) or using [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10), and finally [import the bacpacs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell) to create new databases on the destination (subscription #2) on any Azure SQL logical server.